# Minimum number of jumps required to climb stairs

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, memoization, recurrence

I recently had an interview with Microsoft for an internship and I was asked this question in the interview.

Its basically like, you have 2 parallel staircases and both the staircases have n steps. You start from the bottom and you may move upwards on either of the staircases. Each step on the staircase has a penalty attached to it.
You can also move across both the staircases with some other penalty.

I had to find the minimum penalty that will be imposed for reaching the top.

I tried writing a recurrence relation but I couldn't write anything because of so many variables.

I recently read about dynamic programming and I think this question is related to that.

With some googling, I found that this question is the same as

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/frost-byte-final/challenges/stairway

Can you please give a solution or an approach for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Create two arrays to keep track of the minimal cost to reach every position. Fill both arrays with huge numbers (e.g. 1000000000) and the start of the arrays with the cost of the first step.

Then iterate over all possible steps, and use an inner loop to iterate over all possible jumps.

```
foreach step in (0, N) {
    // we're now sure we know minimal cost to reach this step
    foreach jump in (1,K) {
        // updating minimal costs here
    }
}
```

Now every time we reach `updating` there are 4 possible moves to consider:

- from A[step] to A[step+jump]
- from A[step] to B[step+jump]
- from B[step] to A[step+jump]
- from B[step] to B[step+jump]

For each of these moves you need to compute the cost. Because you already know that you have the optimal cost to reach A[step] and B[step] this is easy. It's not guaranteed this new move is an improvement, so only update the target cost in your array if the new cost is lower then the cost already there.

Comment: This is a well-explained simple breadth-first search. I may have.. overgeneralized my approach.

Comment: @Stef: I think this approach is similar to http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45073/minimum-number-of-jumps-required-to-climb-stairs, no?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a directed graph search? Any kind of simple pathfinding algorithm could handle this. See

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Just make sure you enforce the directional of the stairs (up only) and account for penalties (edge weights).

### [Worked solution](https://github.com/Shadowen/StaircaseChallenge)

Of course, you could do it with dynamic programming, but I wouldn't be the one to ask for that...

Comment: I realize I didn't address jumps. That's because I'm not really clear on that: Are you allowed to take "steps" of size K or are you allowed to "take K free steps"..? It's not too clear in the site you linked.

Comment: it means steps of size k

Comment: can you please write some small code to illustrate your approach?

Comment: Are you confused about the shape of the graph, or the algorithm itself? There are plenty of [good tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding) on straightforward, grid based pathfinding. This is an extension of that logic to a non-square graph.

Comment: actually i just started my 3rd year in college and i am fairly new to programming concepts. I will definitely look into the tutorial you gave but could you please give me a working solution for this problem? I have been trying to solve it since the last 3 days

Answer (score -1):

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

```
public static int csmj(int []a,int src,int[] dp){
     
     if(src>=a.length){
         return Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
     }
     
     
     if(src==a.length-1){
         return 0;
     }   
     
     if(dp[src]!=0){
         return dp[src];
     }

        int count=Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
        for(int i=1;i<=a[src];i++){
            
            count = Math.min( count , csmj(a,src+i,dp)+1 );
        }
        
        dp[src] = count;
        
        return count;
}

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
   
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    
    int minJumps = csmj(a,0,new int[n]); 
    System.out.println(minJumps);

}
```

}

bro you can have look at that solution my intuition is that